# Removing objects in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a Windows Form Application and I want to remove some objects when I use the Menu Strip.

[image]

[image]

I want to remove the objects from the form  when I press "Descarregar cashmatic".
Is it possible?

Comment: How do you store these objects? Are they class variables or in a list?

Comment: What objects? Do you mean hiding some controls?

Comment: @Maaaaa I only have a button there. But for each menustrip I want a diferent button.

Comment: @stuartd I think it might work.

Comment: Show us some code of your form and maybe we can help you.. Specifically your code about the menustrip but it looks like it is done using the designer

Comment: @LuisCosta you can use `form_name -= control_name;` or `control_name.visible = false`

Comment: @JordyvanEijk I'm not working on code so far because if the method I want doesnt work I didnt waste time on code.

Comment: @JesseR.Jose I'll try that. I'll post here if works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that you have to create the `on_Click` event. Only adding the control property `controlName.visible` and set it on false, it will automatically hidden from the list.

```
private void controlName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    controlName.visible = false;
}
```

I hope this help you.